# Indian license and learning permit in California

Tags: usa, driving-license, california

I have a car and have given the written test in California. So ideally I know that I can drive with one person with a permanent license with me. I wanted to ask whether my friend from India who has Indian permanent license can sit beside me and I can drive? He came to USA in 2012 with me, but he entered California just 20 days ago. I heard from some of my friends that he can sit along with me and I can drive.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming (as it sounds from your question) that you do not hold a valid driver license from your home country - your friend **cannot** sit beside you when you drive. The person sitting beside you must have a valid **California** license. See [the information at the CA DMV](http://www.dmv.ca.gov/dl/dl_info.htm#two500):

> You will then be issued a permit if you have never been licensed
>   before. When you practice, you must have an accompanying adult who is
>   18 years of age or older, with a **valid California license**. This person
>   must be close enough to you to take control of the vehicle if
>   necessary. It is illegal for you to drive alone.

If you do have a valid driver license from your home country - CA recognizes it (if it is in English), however you must apply for a CA license within 10 days of becoming CA resident.